# need to validate a page with jsplumb that has a connection and endpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I have a page with **endpoints** connected with connector.
suppose deleting any connection between two endpoints the endpoint remain unconnected.

- I need to validate the page that must check whether all the endpoints
  have connection.
- If all the endpoints have connection it must    validate as true
  otherwise it must validate as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, when creating the endpoints store the endpoint unique id
  in an array for ex. the endpoint will be displayed in div store that
  unique div id in an array collection, for example, i am storing in
  totEndPoints(Array).

  So u will get the count of totEndPoints available.
- Second find the connections using jsPlumb.getConnections() and for
  each connection find the sourceId and targetId store that id's in an
  array (ex:jsArray)

  Remove the duplicate id's present in this array (jsArray).

  Based on count you can validate. if the count is equal all the endpoints have connection otherwise any of the end point does not have the connection.

  function fnValidatePage() {

  ```
  var jsArray = [];
   $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (index, item) {
       jsArray.push(item.sourceId);
       jsArray.push(item.targetId);
   });
   jsArray = jsArray.removeDuplicates();
              var totEndPoints = [];
          $.each($('.w'), function (index, item) {
              totEndPoints.push(item.id);
          });

          if (jsArray.length == totEndPoints.length)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
  ```